# Is there a way to save a TFX DatasetFeatureStatisticsList?

Tags: tfx

Saving a TFX DatasetFeatureStatisticsList to disk (binary)

After computing data statistics from CSV files with tfdv.generate_statistics_from_csv I can't find a good way to save it other than using tfdv.write_stats_text. This, however, saves it in text format, and I want to store it as a serialized DatasetFeatureStatisticsList proto to be able to use it as input to SchemaGen.

Any suggestions?